# Box plot for one row of a (frequency) table

Tags: r

I have a data set as a .csv file (basically: people's wine choice in relation to the origin of the ambient music playing). Reading this as a dataframe results in a df looking like this:

```
   Music   Wine
1  French  French
2  Italian French
3  None    Italian
4  Italian Italian
5  French  Other
...
```

As a table, it looks like this:

```
          Wine
Music        Other    French      Italian
French       35       39            1
None         43       30           11
Italian      35       30           19
```

Now I want to create a frequency diagram that ONLY plots the relative distribution of purchases made with Music == "None". So basically I'd get Other = 0.511904, French = 0.3571429, Italian = 0.1309524.

Now my problem is subsetting this table isn't working.

```
noMusic <- prop.table(table(data[data$Music == "None"]))
geenMuziekTabel <- prop.table(table(data[data$Music == "None"]))
```

Both result in this:

```
[1] 0.144032922 0.004115226 0.045267490 0.078189300          NA          NA          NA          NA
 [9]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[17]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[25]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[33]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[41]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[49]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[57]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[65]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[73]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
[81]          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I thought: maybe I should subset my dataframe FIRST and THEN make a proportional table out of it, but R seems to remember that there was other data, and make this table:

```
          Wine
Music        Other    French      Italian
French       0        0             0
None         43       30           11
Italian      0        0            0
```

I've tried a number of different things, too, but can't figure it out. Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: the solution, based on the accepted answer, is as follows:

```
noMusicTable <- prop.table(table(musicwine$Wine[musicwine$Music == "None"]))
#noMusicTable <- prop.table(table(subset(musicwine, Music == "None", select = Wine)))
noMusicDF <- as.data.frame(noMusicTable)
# need to declare x and y explicitly; use stat = 'identity' to map bars to y-variable
ggplot(noMusicDF, mapping = aes(x = Var1, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill='red')
```

Comment: Check this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387128/9699371)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here three ways to subset correctly:

```
dat <- read.table(text = 
  "Music   Wine
   French  French
   Italian French
   None    Italian
   Italian Italian
   French  Other", header = TRUE)

# Two different ways to subset
prop.table(table(dat$Wine[dat$Music == "None"]))
prop.table(table(subset(dat, Music == "None", select = Wine)))

# With dplyr and piping
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  filter(Music == "None") %>% 
  select(Wine) %>% 
  table() %>% 
  prop.table()
```

Comment: Ah, 2 hours of tearing my hair out looking for the answer and it was as simple as that. Thank you.